# Not recognizing the class

Tags: java, class

This is the code that is meant to call a class called Couple and yet
it doesn't recognize the class why is this?

```java
public class AgencyInterFace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Couple c = new Couple();
        int choice, position;

        showSelection();
        choice = console.nextInt();
        while (choice != 9) {
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    addCouple();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    position = console.nextInt();
                    testCouple(position);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    position = console.nextInt();
                    displayCouple(position);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
            } //end switch
            showSelection();
            choice = console.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static void showSelection() {
        System.out.println("Select and enter");
        System.out.println("1 - add a new couple");
        System.out.println("2 - test a couple");
        System.out.println("3 - display couple");
        System.out.println("9 - exit");
    }

    public static void addCouple() {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String herName, hisName;
        int herAge, hisAge, ageDiff;

        System.out.print("her name: ");
        herName = console.nextLine();
        System.out.print("her age: ");
        herAge = console.nextInt();
        System.out.print("his name: ");
        hisName = console.nextLine();
        System.out.print("his age: ");
        hisAge = console.nextInt();

        ageDiff = herAge - hisAge;
        c.addData(herName, herAge, ageDiff, hisName, hisAge, ageDiff);
    }

    public static void testCouple(int position) {
        System.out.println(c.test(position));
    }

    public static void displayCouple(int position) {
        System.out.println(c.display(position));
    }

    public static void averageAge(int position) {
        System.out.println(c.avgAge());
    }

    public static void maxDifference(int position) {
        System.out.println(c.maxDif(position));
    }

    public static void averageDifference(int position) {
        System.out.println(c.avgDif(position));
    }
}//end of class
```

This code is the class that is meant to be called and that is not
being recognized and is unable to be called.

```java
public class Couple {
    final private int MAX = 5;
    private Person[] p1, p2;
    private int total;

    public Couple() {
        p1 = new Person[MAX];
        p2 = new Person[MAX];
        total = 0;
    }

    private void setData1(Person p, String name, int age, int ageDiff) {
        p.setName(name);
        p.setAge(age);
    }

    public String test(int pos) {
        if (pos != -1) {
            if (p1[pos].getAge() < p2[pos].getAge()) return ("GOOD FOR 
            "+p2[pos].getName()+" !");
            else return ("GOOD 
            FOR "+p1[pos].getName()+" !");
        }
        return "error";
    }

    public void addData(String name1, int age1, int ageDiff1, String
            name2, int age2, int ageDiff2) {
        p1[total] = new Person();
        p2[total] = new Person();
        setData1(p1[total], name1, age1, ageDiff1);
        setData1(p2[total], name2, age2, ageDiff2);
        total++;
    }

    public String display(int position) {
        if (position != -1)
            return ("p1: " + p1[position].getName() + " 
        "+p1[position].getAge()+" / n "+" p2:
        "+p2[position].getName()+"
        "+p2[position].getAge());
                else
        return ("error");
    }

    public String avgAge(int position) {
        double avg = 0;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            sum += p1[total].getAge();
            sum += p2[total].getAge();
        }
        avg = sum / position;
        return ("The average age is: " + avg);
    }

    public void ageDifference(int position) {
        double ageDif = 0.0;
        double ageSum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            if (p1[total].getAge() < p2[total].getAge()) {
                ageSum = p2[total].getAge() - p1[total].getAge();
            } else {
                ageSum = p1[total].getAge() - p2[total].getAge();
            }
            ageSum = ageDif;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this have something to do with the name of the 'Couple' file or how
I call the class. I am getting an 'Undeclared Variable' error.

Comment: "*Is this have something to do with the name of the 'Couple' file or how I call the class.*"* - What do you mean by "*this*"? Do you have a compilation error? Runtime Exception? Unexpected behaviour? Please [edit] the post and clarify what the actual problem is.

Comment: Where did you declare `c`?  How?   It is saying that it doesn't recognize a **variable** ... not a class/

Comment: Please [edit] the post and include the compiler error, as well as all relevant code and highlight the line producing the error.

Comment: I have not declared c but I have got the structure of this program of my Uni website

Comment: Well the compiler is saying *"what is this `c` you are trying to use?"*.  You need to declare it.  In Java, variables must be declared before they are used.

Comment: How do I declare it. Do I do it just like a normal variable

Comment: You need to tell the program, what c is.
e.g. Couple c = new Couple();

Comment: It depends.  It it a normal variable?  (And what do you mean by "normal"?  There are a number of kinds of variable in Java, and they are all normal.)  We can't tell you how or where to declare `c` without more context.

Comment: I just need to be able to call the class 'couple', it has been declared at the begging at the agency interface file to make a new couple when called

Comment: Without seeing the code that produces the error, we cannot help.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  You don't declare variables in interfaces.  And the code (the methods) where you are using `c` cannot appear in an interface.  Show us the real code.

Comment: I have just updated the code its all the code there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `c` inside your `main()` method. Therefore it is not visible in your other methods. Either pass c as a parameter to your other methods or make it a (static) property of the `AgencyInterFace` class instead of a local variable of `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

**USING STATIC METHODS**

If you want to call a method of the class, e.g. `test(int position)`, without creating a variable c, you need to make this method static:

```
public static String test(int pos) {
   if (pos!=-1)  {
        if (p1[pos].getAge()<p2[pos].getAge()) return("GOOD FOR "+p2[pos].getName()+"!");
        else return("GOOD FOR"+p1[pos].getName()+"!");
       }
       return "error";
}
```

In this case, your arrays `p1[]` and `p2[]` would also need to be static --> they would only be created one time.

And example for making your arrays static:

```
private static Person[] p1 = new Person[MAX],
    p2 = new Person[MAX];
```

Now you can call this method of the class using `Couple.test(position)` and it will return a String.

**USING NON-STATIC METHODS**

If you want to create multiple references of the class Couple, in that p1[] and p2[] should contain different values, you need to create a reference of the class Couple.

You can implement this by telling the program, what c is:

```
Couple c = new Couple();
```

*Edit:*

I see that you have created a couple, but not at the right place. If you create your couple inside of the `main()` method, you cannot use it anywhere except in this method. You should declare it in your class:

```
public class AgencyInterFace {
    private static Couple c = new Couple(); //<-- here
    
    // main-method

    // other methods
}
```